# Diode datasheet: What is "AI PCB" in the image?

Tags: power, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

What does "mounted on AI PCB" mean? Please explain with some pictorial examples.

Comment: That's not "AI", but "Al" (uppercase A followed by lowercase L), the symbol for the element Aluminium. The font used in the datasheet appears to render lowercase L the same as a capital I, which is somewhat common with sans-serif fonts.

Answer (score 9):

"Al PCB" refers to an [aluminum core PCB.](https://www.pcbunlimited.com/metal-core/)

[image]

The aluminum core conducts heat away from the circuit, keeping the components cooler.

The diagrams in the question reflect this effect.  The current carrying capacity of the IC is much higher when mounted on an aluminum core PCB.  The aluminum core gets rid of the heat fast enough to keep the IC from overheating, thereby increasing the current carrying capability.

Comment: Seems like to reduce heating issues Where is the exposed area of that aluminum substrate?

Comment: @AmitM it is not exposed. The dielectric is thin enough to conduct heat.